# Eagle: Naming Pins Quickly

Tags: eaglecad

Is it possible to execute a sequential command from Eagle's input line? I want to do something like this:

```
name 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...,100
```

so that I can avoid clicking hundreds of times and just click 100 times to name these massive IO systems. I'm finding that clicking a net and then naming it is just awfully slow. If there's no way to do the above, how can I connect many, many pins to each other quickly?

Comment: Are you referring to the reference designator ("U2", "X1", "R3", etc...) or the name that Eagle uses for each component that doesn't typically get printed on the physical board?

Comment: @Funkyguy I believe he's referring to net names, so that he can simply name a hundred nets at once instead of drawing a hundred wires and naming each wire.

Comment: @derstrom8 ah, I got nothing for that then...

Comment: I think the BUS tool is what your looking for.

Comment: I found the following ULP: https://github.com/jamesfowkes/Eagle-ULPs/blob/master/sequential-naming.ulp .
Not quite sure if that's what you're looking for, but may be worth a try?

Comment: I'm just trying to find a way to be able to click many nets, one after the other, without having to type "name x" and then click etc. The github project seems promising, but it doesn't actually allow me to name thing sequentially when I try it.

Comment: That tool actually renames components, rather than nets.

Comment: @vini_i The bus tool doesn't speed things up at all. You actually click even more.

Answer (score 2):

The bus tool in Eagle allows quickly connecting many pins together and name NETs all at the same time. Here is a good video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-9JMKMi2uY

Comment: Thanks for the link! It seems the bus tool still requires you to click at least 4 times per connection. This is horribly inefficient!

Comment: The tool keeps you from having to type in the name of the net every time.